# How to get URL variables from AJAX call in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, request

I am executing Javascript code from an AJAX call like this:

```
function loadViewViaAjax(url) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        success: function(objServerResponse) {
            var responseText = objServerResponse.responseText;
            var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
            while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText)) {
                eval(scripts[1]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And I send parameters in the URL like this:

[image]

I get the values like this with PHP and Javascript:

```
alert('the URL from PHP: [<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>]');
alert('the URL from javascript: [' + window.location.href + ']');
```

While PHP gives me the request URI so I have access to the URL variables (also via $_GET):

[image]

I cannot get the URL variables with Javascript by reading the `window.location.href` since it is the URL of the parent page instead of the AJAX call:

[image]

**How with Javascript can I get the URL from the AJAX call instead of from the parent page?**

Comment: ist't the url variable enough ? (*do you want the `eval` code to have access to the url?*)

Comment: Are you trying to pass information between two windows or frames? Or are you processing the information with javascript and expecting a response?

Comment: I have a situation where I can't use PHP so I have to use Javascript  to get "targetRegion=tab1" as I do with PHP but can't find how, i.e. something like with `window.location.request_uri`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem turned out to simply be a misunderstanding of scope: the javascript I am executing with eval has access to the variables in the main script so there is no need to pass values.